# How do you edit a .rds file in RStudio?

Tags: r

I am trying to run an R script that I've inherited from a colleague. This script references a .rds file called config.rds. It stores some configuration settings. I need to change those settings. However, when I attempt to open the file in the Rstudio editor, a "Load R object" prompt pops up. I cannot figure out how to open the file for editing.

Comment: rds files are serialized, you don't want to edit the file directly. Load the object, change the things you need changed and then re-save the new object.

Comment: https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/readRDS.html

Answer (score 4):

You can't open the file for editing - it is a *binary* file that stores the internal representation of R data objects.

You can only really read it into R to create a new R object, and then save a modified copy of that R object into a new or (the same) .RDS file. Example:

```
config = readRDS("config.rds")
config$username = "fnord"
saveRDS(config, "config.rds")
```